# PHP - merge properties of objects in two arrays by a certain property

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, merge

I have two arrays :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 0
            [duration] => 1382
            [month] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 0
            [duration] => 2649
            [month] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 176.30260467529297
            [duration] => 3312
            [month] => 5
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 2214.396824836731
            [duration] => 0
            [month] => 6
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 3762.13547706604
            [duration] => 3394
            [month] => 8
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count1] => 2426
            [count2] => 66
            [month] => 5
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count1] => 7550
            [count2] => 773
            [month] => 6
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count1] => 13288
            [count2] => 1536
            [month] => 7
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count1] => 3596
            [count2] => 762
            [month] => 8
        )

)
```

I want to merge them so all the properties for a given `month` would be together. Desired result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 0
            [duration] => 1382
            [month] => 3
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 0
            [duration] => 2649
            [month] => 4
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 176.30260467529297
            [duration] => 3312
            [count1] => 2426
            [count2] => 66
            [month] => 5
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 2214.396824836731
            [duration] => 0
            [count1] => 7550
            [count2] => 773
            [month] => 6
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [count1] => 13288
            [count2] => 1536
            [month] => 7
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [data] => 3762.13547706604
            [duration] => 3394
            [count1] => 3596
            [count2] => 762
            [month] => 8
        )

)
```

Granted, I could do it with two nasty loops, by setting the month as the key for a common table and shoving everything in it, I guess. I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: with the months as keys and arrays instead of objects it would be a simple call to `array_merge_recursive()`.

Comment: Sure but... If I have to go about making loops to transform both arrays of objects into arrays with `months` as keys, I may as well do the merging work in the loop don't you think ? :D

Comment: it somewhat depends on what the data source is.

Comment: `array_merge_recursive()` absolutely will not be reliable because the month values are numeric and that function will not properly respect numeric keys while grouping.  Proof: https://3v4l.org/a3dd1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to tolerate at least "two nasty loops" because you need to  merge two arrays containing objects by a specific column.  Identifying the relating column between the two arrays is done by setting the month value as the first level key, then "shoving" data into that group.

In the pursuit of brevity, you can call `array_column()` to prepare the entire first array for grouping.  Then you will need to manually iterate the rows of the second array AND if the month group already exists, iterate all of its properties because PHP does not allow you to merge objects like arrays (this is why @Elementary chose to use type casting three times just to merge the data).

Finally, you want to sort by month, so call `ksort()`, then remove the temporary first level keys with `array_values()` if you like.

I expect that you will find this approach to be most efficient because only the second array is iterated and using the first array as a lookup and result array will be the swiftest way to related data from the two arrays.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GqDJB))

```
$result = array_column($array1, null, 'month');
foreach ($array2 as $obj) {
    if (!isset($result[$obj->month])) {
        $result[$obj->month] = $obj;
    } else {
        foreach ($obj as $k => $v) {
            $result[$obj->month]->$k = $v;
        }
    }
}
ksort($result);
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Answer (score 1):

this reproduce your arrays of object:

```
$array1=Array
(

       (object) array(
            'data' => 0,
            'duration' => 1382,
            'month' => 3,
        ),

     (object)array
        (
            'data' => 0,
            'duration' => 2649,
            'month' => 4,
        )

   ,

     (object)array(
            'data' => 176.30260467529297,
            'duration' => 3312,
            'month' => 5,
        )

    ,

    (object)array(
            'data' => 2214.396824836731,
            'duration' => 0,
            'month' => 6,
        )

    ,

     (object)array(
            'data' => 3762.13547706604,
            'duration' => 3394,
            'month' => 8,
        )

);

$array2=Array
(


     (object)array(
            'count1' => 2426,
            'count2' => 66,
            'month' => 5,
        )

    ,

     (object)array(
            'count1' => 7550,
            'count2' => 773,
            'month' => 6,
        )

   ,

     (object)array(
            'count1' => 13288,
            'count2' => 1536,
            'month' => 7,
        )

   ,

     (object)array(

            'count1' => 3596,
            'count2' => 762,
            'month' => 8,
        )

);
```

and this achieve the merging based on the month property:

```
$merged=[];

foreach($array1 as $key=> $object1){
    $no_match=true;
    foreach($array2 as $object2){
        if($object1->month===$object2->month){
            $data[$key]=(object)array_merge((array)$object1,(array)$object2);
            $no_match=false;
            break;
        }

    }
    if($no_match)
        $data[$key]=$object1;
}

var_dump($data);
```

and the output is:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
    ["data"]=>
    int(0)
    ["duration"]=>
    int(1382)
    ["month"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (3) {
    ["data"]=>
    int(0)
    ["duration"]=>
    int(2649)
    ["month"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#10 (5) {
    ["data"]=>
    float(176.30260467529)
    ["duration"]=>
    int(3312)
    ["month"]=>
    int(5)
    ["count1"]=>
    int(2426)
    ["count2"]=>
    int(66)
  }
  [3]=>
  object(stdClass)#11 (5) {
    ["data"]=>
    float(2214.3968248367)
    ["duration"]=>
    int(0)
    ["month"]=>
    int(6)
    ["count1"]=>
    int(7550)
    ["count2"]=>
    int(773)
  }
  [4]=>
  object(stdClass)#12 (5) {
    ["data"]=>
    float(3762.135477066)
    ["duration"]=>
    int(3394)
    ["month"]=>
    int(8)
    ["count1"]=>
    int(3596)
    ["count2"]=>
    int(762)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I said in the end of my post, doing two loops it's easy - I was looking for a maybe more elegant way to do it but I guess there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help to you, 
Consider you have two array of objects $data and $data1,

```
$finalData = []; // to store final result 
$monthArray = array_column($data1, 'month');

foreach ($data as $index=>$row) {

    $key = array_search($row->id, $monthArray);

    if ($key!==false) {
        $finalData[$index] = (object) array_merge((array) $row, (array) $data1[$key]);
        unset($data1[$key]);
        unset($data[$index]);
        unset($monthArray[$key]);
    }
}

if (count($data)) {
     $finalData = array_merge($finalData, $data);
}

if (count($data1)) {
     $finalData = array_merge($finalData, $data1);
}


print_r($finalData);
```

Please review and let me know in case it help or I missed any case.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not really a more elegant way than the one I had. Thanks for trying though !